# Como funcionam as URL em Django

Tags: python, django, self

Estou desenvolvendo um website django.

Em que eu possuo estas duas estruturas

**main**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from post import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index),
]
```

**app**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path("index/",views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

Eu não entendi o porquê de referenciar as URLS em ambos os arquivos, pois parece que estou chamando as views do meu projeto duas vezes.

Podem me explicar o funcionamento dessas estruturas?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, quando você gera um projeto Django, ele monta uma estrutra inicial que serve de base para você começar a usar o Django admin. Essa app é uma aplicação que o Django vai usar, por isso você vai ter urls para sua aplicação(esse app ai) e urls do Django, e como o Django é a base, ele vai chamar as urls da sua aplicação. Espero que dê para etender.

Mais informações sobre: [urls django](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/django_urls/)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o main seja o seu projeto principal .
 No projeto principal você tem o arquivo urls.py que que faz a rota para as urls dos diversos apps que você pode ter realcionados ao projeto.

ex :

O usuário acessa o site www.sistemagestao.com.br
   O servidor vai bater em main.urls  `path('/', include(home_urls))` e no app "Home" vai ter um arquivo urls.py que vai chamar a view.

Digamos que acesse www.sistemagestao.com.br/clientes, o servidor vai bater em main.urls `path('clientes/', include(clientes_urls))` e será direcionado para o app "Clientes" que também possui um arquivo urls.py com as rotas referentes a clientes que vão encaminhar para as views específicas.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from clientes import urls as clientes_urls
from home importe urls as home_urls

urlpatterns = [  
    path('/', include(home_urls)) 
    path('clientes/', include(clientes_urls)),  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Desculpa se não fui muito claro, faz pouco que também comecei a estudar python e django.

Answer (score 0):

Uso para fazer a segmentação do meu código, 
é possível colocar todas as """rotas"""(URLS) 
em um arquivo só mas ficaria pouco intuitívo.
Por isso coloco as URLS separadas para cada APP.
Evita de mexer nas rotas de outras APPs.

```
 from django.urls import path, include
 from clientes import urls as clientes_urls
 from home importe urls as home_urls

 urlpatterns = [  
     path('/', include(home_urls)) 
     path('clientes/', include(clientes_urls)),  
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```